# Sending output to logfile or STDOUT

Tags: perl, stdout, logfile

I am trying to come up with some logic to give my script an option of where to send the output.

This is a test script I started to write, I started to fizzle out trying to think of the combonations of the two options. I know I am overthinking this too much.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Modules to load
use Getopt::Long;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

my $output = 0;

my $logfile = '';

GetOptions(

    'o' => \$output,
    'l' => \$logfile

);

if (($output == 1) && (! $logfile eq '')){



} elsif (($output == 0)($logfile eq '')){



}
```

If this is of any use be my guest.

Pretty much I want 3 options

0 = off
1 = stdout
2 = logfile

Where I threw a bit of a wrench at myself if when I wanted to add a custom logfile argument. I am under the impression I cannot combine the 2 arg into the same arg, can I?

The places where I will have output to write, I will control with simple `if` statments based on a condition, in my first interation which just allows for output to stdout. I just used the `-o` option and specified `0` or `1`. If it was 1 it wrote the line, if it was 0 it did not.

If any has an easier solution than the one above I am open to anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot combine the arguments, but you can use the value of one to set the other ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the vein of TLP I suggest a `$verbose` and a `$logfile` option, I would also recommend that `$verbose` be implicitly set to true if `$logfile` is used. Use `$verbose` to control `print` commands as usual. The big magic is to use [`select`](http://p3rl.org/select) to control where the `print` sends its output if no filehandle is given.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Modules to load
use Getopt::Long;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

my $verbose = 0;
my $logfile;

GetOptions(

    'verbose' => \$verbose,
    'logfile=s' => \$logfile,

);

if (defined $logfile) {
  $verbose = 1;
  open my $log_handle, '>', $logfile or die "Could not open $logfile";
  # select makes print point to LOGFILE 
  select($log_handle);
}

# do stuff

print "Stuff" if $verbose;
```

Also since `Getopt::Long` gives you long options, I have changed the options names to the human readable `verbose` and `logfile`, however you can use short `-v` or long `--verbose` to your taste.

Comment: If you use a lexical filehandle, declared inside the if block, it will be out of scope outside it, but I wonder if `select()` would still remember it?

Comment: I always recommend lexical filehandle, in this case I used a global bareword for simplicity. `select` should remember, however your should predeclare the handle variable outside the if to prevent it closing the handle when it goes out of scope!

Comment: I have amended to include the lexical filehandle. Since it is in global scope it really isn't very different.

Comment: Actually, I tested it, and `select()` does remember the filehandle, even when it is out of scope. `print "Yada"` works, but `print $fh "Yada"` does not.

Comment: Yes, Perl will retain the value so long as it is in use.

Comment: I am really liking your solution, I will not know until tomorrow whether it works or not.

Comment: @Solignis, let me know, I think it should, my test script works

Comment: It works when I copy your script into my VM where I am working. The thing that is kinda odd is how you use $log_handle, yet no value has been assigned. Could I assign a value like `LOGGER` to it? Without breaking it?

Comment: `$log_handle` is empty when declared, however `open $log_handle, ...` causes it to hold the filehandle. This is now preferred to using a bareword filehandle like `LOGGER`. This is called an Indirect Filehandle (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html#Indirect-Filehandles).

Comment: @Solignis, if it looks odd to you having that `$log_handle` laying around, try what we were discussing above, remove the declaration `my $log_handle;` above, then put a `my` in the `open` line (`open my $log_handle, '>', ...`) now the variable holding the filehandle is local to the `if` block, but `print` will still print to the file

Comment: Yeah this worked out for me. I have been proccupide with other things and have no fully implemented the logger yet. But my test script worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `$verbose` as an option, and an optional `$logfile`. So, if `$verbose` is set, you print, if `$logfile` is set, you print to the log.

Then use:

```
if ($logfile) {
    open STDOUT, '>', $logfile or die $!;
}
print "Yada\n" if $verbose;
```

Or for simplicity:

```
sub myprint {
    return unless $verbose;
    print @_;
}
myprint("Yada\n");
```

Comment: @Solignis Joel's idea with select is probably more correct. I learned something here too. ;)

Comment: @Solignis, you may use a `myprint` command in my example, though that hides its purpose, perhaps you should name the function `log` or `verbose` or something that states why it is called rather than `print`. In truth, `print ... if $verbose` really says what you mean and is readable too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first off, forgive me if this syntax is wrong. Its been a LONG time since I've done any perl, so take this more as a "do this sortof thing" rather than a "copy and paste my answer". With that said, I'd probably just do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Modules to load
use Getopt::Long;
use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

my $output = 0;
my $logfile = '';

GetOptions(

    'o' => \$output,
    'l' => \$logfile

);

if (($output == 1) && (! $logfile eq '')){
    open STDOUT, $logfile
} elsif (($output == 0)($logfile eq '')){
    open STDOUT, "/dev/null"
}

... (do stuff normally here)
```

All I am doing is changing where STDOUT is going by either sending it to the log file or sending it to `/dev/null`

Comment: @TLP, yes, I was just checking that myself :)

Comment: You should also probably `open` for writing with either `>` or `>>`, and check the return value of `open` with `die`.

Comment: Changing STDOUT to do this is unnecessary and prevents restoring STDOUT to normal later if desired, this is what `select` is for.

Comment: @TLP, thus the reason for the comment on "don't quote me on syntax" :)